# Cement vs pressure treated lumber porch

Tags: concrete, deck, porch, pressure-treated

I'm looking to build an enclosed porch between two doors on the side of my house, and I've had contractors opt to either use a 12" concrete slab, or concrete/helical piles with pressure treated wood for the base with pt or composite finish.

I can't seem to get a straight answer on which if any is a better option, especially for longevity.

Located in Ontario so freezing/thawing, lots of temp swings.

Edit:
I am looking for longevity. I don't want to rebuild/replace in 15-20 years. Appearance is irrelevant, have no preference.

This will be at ground level, enclosed with a shingled roof but not insulated. Typical aluminum/glass enclosure.

Rough size is 10'x10'x10'.

I've read PT will last if maintained but I will not be able to apply any sealer to the framing.
On the other hand, I don't know how well a foot of concrete would hold up to 15 freeze/thaw cycles.

Pictures for just for reference of what I'm looking at.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Had small decks/landings done with PT wood in 92.  Outside, no protection, no upkeep.  They are still good.  Ontario also.

Comment: "Better" is a matter of opinion, which is why you're getting different opinions from your contractors. What do _you_ want? Do you want a wood/wood-look porch or do you want a concrete porch? That's the deciding factor and only you can determine that.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific: size? fully enclosed and insulated? porch height above ground if pile&PT? Frostline (6ft?) etc... I vote to keep this question open; the Q&A and discussion will bring many useful insights and considerations.

Comment: 12 " concrete slab seems awfully thick for a porch.

Comment: MY opinion only - I think bare concrete looks very cold compared to wood.  If you're planning on topping that with bricks, slate, or even a rug, that might be a different matter.  But like others have said, this more a question of what you like better.

Comment: Added more info.

Comment: Just add to my comment.  Have no stain or paint on the PT(green stuff) wood, so just plain wood.  Do find like to use a pressure washer on it every so often to remove the slippery stuff(slime) from it.

Comment: This is a subjective question. Even if you strip it to bare longevity, it's a matter of opinion when a thing has reached the end of its life. Concrete would be around much longer, but it will degrade as well.

Answer (score 2):

On longevity - a wood deck should last you long past your 20 year cut off for having to replace.  Here's a covered deck I built ~30 years ago that is still standing.  Only maintenance has been to seal the deck boards every couple of years.

[image]

If you're worried about the structural components, cover the upper edges of the 2x joists with a flexible waterproofing flashing membrane or some 2" copper tape (yeah, I know that's not cheap).  This will keep much of the water out of the deck structure.

Comment: Are you arguing that wood is more durable than concrete? That was the question.

Comment: No, I wasn't arguing that, specifically.  I though it was a more general question of wood vs concrete.  But since you brought it up, there are a number of wood structures around that are older than 100 years.  The Kennecott Mines in Alaska is one, and U Bein Bridge in Myanmar, finished in 1850 are two examples.  And the Horyu Temple in Japan is estimated to be over 1,300 years old.

Comment: And OP did talk about a 15-20 year lifespan.

Answer (score 0):

The cost and effort to maintain are also factors that will affect longevity.

Wood deck repairs are far easier than concrete slab repairs. If there's damage, you'd have a wooden structure fixed by the next season. With concrete, on the other hand, it would be unsightly for years before you muster the courage and cash to fix a slab under a covered space.

If the floor does not have to be on-grade, the wooden base is an attractive and durable option. Just make sure you have ventilation and grading to manage moisture underneath, and provisions to keep weeds and critters out: lay landscape fabric, cover with rock or large gravel, and close it off.

In Ontario you'd probably also be concerned with  mosquitos, and they are more easily fended off if the base is concrete on grade, and not an elevated floor.